# How do I resolve Extension requires Microsoft ODBC driver for SQL Server on Linux Apache

Tags: php, sql-server, linux, apache

I have a Linux server running Apache, and I am very new to both. I am trying to run PHP (version 7.4) scripts to connect to a SQL Server running on a separate box. When I run the code shown below, I receive this errror:

> connection could not be established.
> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac?view=sql-server-ver16) => -49 [code] => -49 [2] => This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server

I initially set this up in a local Windows environment, and it was a simple fix, uncomment the extension=whatever lines in the PHP.INI and make sure I had the proper drivers in the etc directory in c:\PHP.

In Linux, will it be basically the same process? I can edit the php.ini and uncomment all of the extension=whatever lines in the Dynamic Extensions section, but will I need to install specific drivers? Is that a simple sudo apt-get command?

```
<?php
$serverName = "IPaddress\\MSSQLSERVER";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"Tester", "UID"=>"testuser", "PWD"=>"password" );
$con = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if( $con ) {
    echo "connection established.<br />";
}else{
echo "connection could not be established.<br />";
die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

I've read the material at [Installation Tutorial for MS Drivers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac?view=sql-server-ver16) but I'm still a bit lost. Should I force our hosting service to update to php 8.2 instead of trying to deal with v7.4?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: “Should I force our hosting service to update to php 8.2 instead of trying to deal with v7.4” - 7.4 reached EOL at the end of last year, so I would not recommend starting anything new with it. The additional libraries will be installed via PECL per that documentation. See [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/403348) but adjust for your version. PECL is a not as mainstream as core which is why it is a little weirder. At the end of the install, you’ll usually get an .so file that you need to add to the config, similar to the uncommenting your were talking about, but adding instead

Comment: Thanks for that info. I'm going to ask our hosting service to update, and I'm going to try to follow the guide you provided to install what I need. Although I'd rather just hire someone like you to do it for me. This is not my wheelhouse.

Comment: I'm reading through the Additional .ini Files Parsed section of the config page, I see that 20-sqlsrv.ini is installed in the conf.d directory. If that's the case, is it possible I just need to add extension=sqlsrv.so to the php.ini file?